# Unable to paste entire text into Postgres table

Tags: postgresql, powershell, command-prompt

trying to insert data into Postgres table via windows command prompt using copy/paste, but there seems to be a character limit of 4077? tried "different data" and got the same result limited to 4077 characters. so went onto windows power shell. while I was able to paste a bit more characters in power shell, I'm still unable to get all data into the table. for the field of interest, datatype is set to text. no error message, just pasted text that is truncated and cannot be further extended with a follow up paste.

Comment: This is not a limit on the Postgres end: [Character types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html): `text  variable unlimited length`. You will need to add more information to your question: 1) What client are you using to connect to the Postgres database? 2) Where are doing the copy and how?

Comment: Most likely a problem (or limitation) with the Windows command line. But why "paste" at all? Put the statements you want to run into a SQL script then run the script using `\i the_script.sql` from inside `psql`

Comment: postgres db is local. copying text from notepad file and pasting to command prompt. didn't figure it out but for sake of time, i ended up using pgadmin (gui) to insert/update the row which worked.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thx that'll be a future lesson

Answer (score 0):

I came here with the same question and found out it is the psql line-buffer which appears limited to 2048 characters, probably including a null-byte (as usual in C). You can verify this by opening psql, hold a key ('a') on the keyboard and wait until output (and input) stops. (psql version 14.7 used).
Also, in Windows command, I can paste the same very long command without problems as a test; of course that offers no solution by itself.

A very simple remedy, then, is to divide a very long single line command into lines using an LF (or CR-LF in windows) character. When you copy from a file (instead of executing an .sql file with psql -c), because, perhaps like me, you do not want to execute it in one go, hitting a few enters will solve the problem. Few cmd lines are over 2048 characters, anyway.

Anyway I would surely recommend increasing this single line buffer in psql, or better, re-allocate it when insufficient and not use a fixed (stack) variable for this.